# I am working on a discord bot using Python. Everytime I run the program, error shows up "discord module not found." I installed discord.py using pip

Tags: python, discord

I am working on a discord bot using Python. Every time I run the program, error shows up "discord module not found." I installed discord.py using pip.

This is what I wrote when I got the problem

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. That being said, [idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode/)

Comment: How are you trying to run the bot? Are you running it by typing `python <bot name>` into CMD, are you double clicking it in explorer, or are you doing something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.py should work even if it responds with this error. I also have this error, but I just run the file from file explorer and it works from there. If you're using PyCharm or another discord.py shell, then you can just switch to Python 3.5 or higher to get it to work. I was frustrated by this issue too, but I tried it... and it miraculously worked...

Edit: nvm I saw ur picture. there's nothing wrong with your bot - try the following:

1. Did you install discord.py in the command prompt (running it as an admin?) you can easily look it up online for the exact thing you gotta type.
2. Are you using a newer version of Python? It has to be 3.6 or higher.
3. You may not have installed discord properly.
4. Just... run... it...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using python 3.6 or higher or try running these commands

```
pip install discord
pip install discord==(the version you want)
```